# How to solve a start of type error in java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner and was writing a code that would input three integers. It would find the maximum integer and return its position.
code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int getNumberOfMaxParam(int a, int b, int c) {
        int max = a;
        int count = 1;
        if (b > max) {
            count = 2;
        }

        if (c > max) {
            count = 3;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(getNumberOfMaxParam(a, b, c));
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Compilation error
Main.java:1: error: illegal start of type
import java.util.Scanner;
^
Main.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
import java.util.Scanner;
                        ^
2 errors
```

What correction should I make? I've tried to read other answers on the same issue but unlike others I'm not using a try-catch block. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the whole file Main.java? Is there any text above the `import`? There is also an error in the logic. You need to assign to max here: `if(b > max){count=2; max=b;}` or the code will print 3 if a < c < b.

Comment: @Alex There is no text above import. This is the whole file. By the way, thanks for telling the statement I missed

Comment: I just pasted your code to a new text file and it compiles without a problem. How do you compile it?

Comment: @Alex I am actually taking a tutorial at hyperskill. [link](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2726)

Comment: It says 'write just the body of the method'. So don't copy the whole file. The text will be inserted inside already premade program. So paste 11 lines starting with `int max = a;` and ending with `return count;`

Comment: @Alex          I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you got a BOM character in your file?  Did you create using WordPad or something?

Comment: @StephenC      No just VSCode

Comment: I reckon it has to be a stray [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or some other non-printing character in your source code file.  When I copy-and-paste your code from the question into a file and compile it, there are no errors.

Comment: @StephenC Maybe I should report this bug to the tutorial platform

Comment: Only if the file you got from the tutorial platform contains the offending character.  If there really is a BOM in the file you are trying to compile, it shouldn't compile.  Use a hex editor or something to look at the start of the file on your machine.

Comment: @StephenC      I tried without using any local variables and it worked. Please tell if you have any idea why

Comment: Because in your editing of the file you have removed the BOM.  Please note what I said earlier.  I copied your code from the question into a file and compiled it. No errors.  Try doing the same thing yourself.

Comment: @StephenC Can you please explain a little about BOM since google doesn't show anything relative and I'm a beginner. By the way, it compiles in the PC but fails in the tutorial (probably of the BOM)

Comment: Did you read the link I gave to you already?

Comment: @StephenC I did but couldn't understand much. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing the issue, I can say this particular problem does not require you to have a class declaration. It is enough to provide only method's signature and body, even if IDEA gives you a warning.

[image]

As you see, the solution was accepted, despite the warning.

This might be confusing, as other problems on this platform do require you to provide class declaration. I think, it depends on the author of the particular problem.

Also, please note, the [task](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2726) does not ask you for an input, so import of `java.util.Scanner` and the corresponding method are not needed.

I advise you to reset the problem by pressing `Solve again` button on the site and start over again. If you are having trouble resetting it, remove the problem's module from the project or delete it from the disk first.